# Good or bad idea to prefix all classes with same abbreviation?

Tags: ios, windows, coding-style, standards, computer-science

So in practically all my programs I wrote I always prefixed every class I created with the same abbreviation that was in relation to the program. So for instance say I wrote an app called GasStationDeluxe. I would make a class called GSDGasStation or GSDGasPump etc. Now I always thought that is a good idea because it would group together all thelse classes I created in intellisense to make it easier for me and other programmers to find the classes I created.

Yet, I'm reading a book called "Clean Code: A Handbook of agIle software craftsmanship" and I just read a part in a chapter where it says it's not a good idea to do that becasue auto complete will bring you back a list of tons of classes. So who else codes this way? Do you think it's a good or bad idea to code with the same prefix before each class? If yes or no, then why?

Comment: It's a common way to prefix classes in languages don't have namespace just like OC

Comment: I agree with the previous. If your language does not support namespace/packages, that's a way to avoid collisions. Microsoft took prefixes to the absurd and people (to do like Microsoft) would follow their idiocy and hyper-prefix. That is a bad coding practice.

Comment: Whats odd is that if it is considered "Bad Practice" why does apple do it in their iOS framework. Many classes have the NS, CG or CA prefix to classes that are apart of that library. I wonder what the developers at apple have to say about this

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this, but you will sometimes see it done in solutions with multiple projects like GSD.App or GSD.Core

I was always that in a class called Customer.cs, you might not want to make the name field CustomeName but just Name as your already in the customer class so what is it adding. I suppose the same is true in your case of classes.

What if you want to reuse your classes elsewhere? I would say from the vast majority of code examples I come across and other peoples code I read, this isn’t common practice.

I suppose really it’s up to you and any team you work with, as long as it’s consistent.

I wonder what .net would look like if Microsoft prefixed everything!

Comment: Well wouldn't that be a little different since .net is a framework in and of itself. This is in relation to building say an application on mobile or even a regular program which is built upon the underlying framework. To me its good practice because you are separating the code you build from the code of the framework.

What is odd is that apple does this in their framework. For instance alot of classes start with NS, or CA, or CG. SO if apple does it how come its considered bad practice?